# main() parameters mess up array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

I've been writing a C study program on encryption and met an unexpected problem:

When I include parameters into `main()` function (as `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`) and try to declare a separate array of chars in my code (`char array[2] = {'a','b'};`), which has nothing to do with `main()` arguments, that array somehow gets length of 8 instead of 2 and some junk is added to it when I try to print it out (e.g. `ab ?iQ?`).

Whereas if I declare `main()` without any parameters (`int main()`), the declared char array behaves normally: gets size of 2 and prints out like `ab`.

Do parameters in `main()` function set limits on minimum size of arrays in code?

Comment: `that array somehow gets length of 8 instead of 2` why do you say that?

Comment: that is value returned by strlen(array) function

Comment: You cannot put a string with two characters in an array with space for 2 bytes. The string needs 3 bytes. You can put two bytes in the array but then it's not a string ... and *string* functions do not work with it.

Comment: An array of characters is not necessarily a null-terminated string... Note that the code `array[] = "ab"` is equal to `array[] = {'a','b','\0'}`

Comment: If you need to find the actual size of the array, rather than the length of the string stored in it, use `((sizeof array) / (sizeof array[0]))`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strlen()` on a `char` array without a `nul` termination byte causes undefined behavior.

A string in c, consists of a sequence of non-`nul` bytes terminated by a `nul` -> `'\0'` byte, so this

```
char array[2] = {'a','b'};
```

should be

```
char array[3] = {'a', 'b', '\0'};
```

for `strlen()` to work properly.

You can implement a `strlen()` like this

```
size_t stringlength(const char *string)
  {
      size_t length;
      length = 0;
      while (string[length] != '\0')
          length++;
      return length;
  }
```

so if the `'\0'` is not there, it will keep reading from the array beond it's bounds cause the undefined behavior mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, that works! If I understand it right, instruction like 'char array[3] = {'a', 'b'}' would add 'nul' automatically?

Comment: Yes. `char array[3] = {'a', 'b'};` adds a NUL. There is no partial initialization in C. All elements are initialized, to `0` in the absence of another value.

Comment: @DenysTriasunov: With `char array[3] = {'a', 'b'}`, the compiler wouldn't add the null-character automatically, but with `char array[3] = "ab"` it would BTW, you don't really need to specify that `3`.

Comment: @barakmanos: `char array[30] = {'a', 'b'};` is exactly equal to `char array[30] = {'a', 'b', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`